# The third dropdown value is not showing in print_r

Tags: php, ajax, oracle

I am designing triple dropdown list that connected to oracle DB. when user select the 3 values, it must update the values to the db. But I am having problem that the 3rd dropdown is not showing in print_r that means i cant put the 3rd value in the database

this is the JS for the program,

```
function getThickness(projectName) {        

    var strURL="findThickness.php?project="+projectName;
    var req = getXMLHTTP();

    if (req) {

        req.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (req.readyState == 4) {
                // only if "OK"
                if (req.status == 200) {                        
                    document.getElementById("thicknessDiv").innerHTML=req.responseText;
                    document.getElementById("baseplateDiv").innerHTML='<select name="baseplate">'+
                    '<option>Select Baseplate</option>'+'</select>';                        
                } else {
                    alert("Problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                }
            }               
        }           
        req.open("GET", strURL, true);
        req.send(null);
    }       
}

function getBaseplate(projectName,thicknessVal) {       
    var strURL="findBaseplate.php?project="+projectName+"&thicknessValue="+thicknessVal;
    var req = getXMLHTTP();

    if (req) {
        req.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (req.readyState == 4) {
                // only if "OK"
                if (req.status == 200) {                        
                    document.getElementById("baseplateDiv").innerHTML=req.responseText;                     
                } else {
                    alert("Problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                }
            }               
        }           
        req.open("GET", strURL, true);
        req.send(null);
    }

}
```

and findThickness.php,

```
<?php 
$projectName = strval($_GET['project']); 

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT THICKNESS FROM COMPONENT_CUTTING WHERE PROJECT_NAME = :projectName";
$result = oci_parse($conn, $query);

oci_bind_by_name($result, ":projectName", $projectName);

oci_execute($result);

?>

<select name="thickness" onChange="getBaseplate('<?php echo $projectName?>',(this.value));">

<option>Select Thickness</option>
    <?php while ($row = oci_fetch_array($result, OCI_BOTH)) { ?>
<option value=<?php echo $row['THICKNESS']?>><?php echo $row['THICKNESS']?></option>
    <?php } ?>

</select>
```

and findBasePlate.php is like this

```
<?php 
$projectName    = strval($_GET['project']); 
$thicknessValue = intval($_GET['thicknessValue']);

$query = "SELECT BASE_PLATE FROM COMPONENT_CUTTING WHERE THICKNESS = :thicknessVal AND PROJECT_NAME = :projectName";
$result = oci_parse($conn, $query);

oci_bind_by_name($result, ":projectName", $projectName);
oci_bind_by_name($result, ":thicknessVal", $thicknessValue);

oci_execute($result);
?>


<select name="baseplate">

<option>Select Baseplate</option>
<?php 
    while($row = oci_fetch_array($result, OCI_BOTH)) { ?>
        <option value><?php echo $row['BASE_PLATE']?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

and on the save.php that called when user click submit theres a print_r that shows the value and its just showing like this,

```
Array ( [projectName] => ECOFATTYACHID [thickness] => 28 [baseplate] => [quantityToCut] => 4 [text_remarks] => [submit] => Submit Request )
```

I dont know whats wrong with my code. so please advise me with this and i greatly appreciated you guys help

Comment: Sidenote: Do put this in quotes `<option value=<?php echo $row['THICKNESS']?>>` such as `<option value="<?php echo $row['THICKNESS']?>">` it could be interpreted as `<option value=option_xxx>` and may not give the intended results.

Comment: You also need to change `<option value><?php echo $row['BASE_PLATE']?></option>` to `<option><?php echo $row['BASE_PLATE']?></option>` removing `value`

Comment: You're welcome. Let me know if you want me to make it an answer to close the question.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes please do Fred ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do put this in quotes `<option value=<?php echo $row['THICKNESS']?>>`
such as `<option value="<?php echo $row['THICKNESS']?>">`
it will be interpreted as `<option value=option_xxx>` and may not give the intended results.

You also need to change `<option value><?php echo $row['BASE_PLATE']?></option>` to `<option><?php echo $row['BASE_PLATE']?></option>` removing `value`